# How to write select named query in jpa for EmbeddedId?

Tags: sql, jpa, named-query

I have a JPA entity called Parent and inside that there is embeddedPrimary key as Child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@NamedQuery(?????)
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPK child;
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "DEALERID")
    private String dealerId;

    @Column(name = "BRANDID")
    private Long brandId;
..
}
```

How can I write named Query in Parent class so that i can perform select on dealerId and brandId from ChildPk.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p.child.dealerId = ? and p.child.brandId=?